# How to get environment of child process in Python

Tags: python, shell

I need to source the environment of child process. I have a c-shell script(really complicated) that sets many environment variables and I want to use them in the parent process. I doing something like this:

```
subprocess.call(['set_env_vars.csh;    env>crazy_vars.log' shell=True])
```

In this way I am trying to get the env of child process but this method is not working as I think commands after semicolon are treated as separate processes.

A possible solution is that I created another c-shell script and put those two commands in there and then call that script in python but thats a dirty way.

Is there a way to make two commands as the part of same process.

Thanks

Comment: Why not copy the env and set the environment variables using os.environ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do but first I need to get the environment variables(in a file) of child process.

Answer (score 2):

On my system (as with many others) the shell is bash, not csh, so explicitly invoking csh is a good idea. Also, you need to source, not execute *set_env_vars.csh*:

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/csh', '-c', 'source set_env_vars.csh; env > crazy_vars.log'])
```